# Mass resolution in cosmological simulations

Tags: galaxy, cosmology, dark-matter, mass, n-body-simulations

I've been reading papers about different cosmological simulations and they all talk about the "mass resolution" of those. Can someone please explain what does "mass resolution" mean in this case? I know it has something to do with the number of particles employed in the simulation or something like that? But I can't seem to grasp a full understanding...